# Displaying a multi-level recursivelycreated array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I've created an array, that containers multiple levels of 'child' arrays.

```
$this->project_tasks: Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [person_name] => User 1
        [reports_to_id] => 
        [task_id] => 1123
        [task_name] => Main Task
        [sub_task_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [person_name] => User 1
                        [reports_to_id] => 1123
                        [task_id] => 1124
                        [task_name] => sub Task 1-1
                        [sub_task_id] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [person_name] => User 1
                                        [reports_to_id] => 1124
                                        [task_id] => 1125
                                        [task_name] => sub Task 1-1-1

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [person_name] => User 1
                        [reports_to_id] => 1123
                        [task_id] => 1127
                        [task_name] => sub Task 1-2
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [person_name] => User 1
        [reports_to_id] => 
        [task_id] => 1126
        [task_name] => Main Task 2
    )

)
```

Creating the array is no problem, the current issue is how do I iterate over the entire data set in such a way that it could display as so:

```
1123 - Main Task
  1124 - sub Task 1-1
    1125 - sub Task 1-1-1
  1127 - sub Task 1-2
  ...
1126 - Main Task 2
  ...
etc...
```

I found array_walk_recursive() but it wont do keys that contain arrays. Also, the array structure has to be uncaring about how 'deep' the recursion goes. Could be 10+ levels, can not matter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use RecursiveIteratorIterator http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php#recursiveiteratoriterator.example.basic

Comment: That works for the array data, however the RecursiveIteratorIterator does not provide how many levels deep a specific array is. That becomes a problem when moving 'up' a level to a new sibling array of the array being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function customRecursiveWalk($array,$level){
    $size = count($array);

    for ($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) {

        for ($j=0;$j<$level;$j++)
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;"; //Print the indentation level

        //Print the current task id and the task name
        echo($array[$i]['task_id'] ." - ".$array[$i]['task_name']);
        echo '<br/>';

        //Call the recursive walk for the child
        customRecursiveWalk($array[$i]['sub_task_id'],$level+1);
    }
}

customRecursiveWalk($this->project_tasks,0);
```

Comment: Close, very close. I'll post the final solutions if I can get it working.

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Maybe I can try to fix it

Comment: Not a thing, It was me having a terrible day. After some slight changes it works perfectly. TY @Fábio Hiroki.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the full usecase, but it seems that a simple recursive function would do the trick here. I've used ul/li to establish the multiple levels, but that is of course not required -- for example, I also included a function that will give you a flat array with the tasks listed in order.

First, the HTML version:

```
function listTasks($list, $level=0) {
    print '<li>'.$list['task_id'].' - '.$list['task_name'];
    if (array_key_exists('sub_task_id', $list)) {
        print '<br><ul>';
        foreach ($list['sub_task_id'] as $subtasks) {
            listTasks($subtasks, $level+1);
        }
        print '</ul>';
    }
    print '</li>';
}
print '<ul>';
foreach ($a as $tasks) {
    listTasks($tasks, 1);
}
print '</ul>';
```

Sample output:

```
1123 - Main Task
    1124 - sub Task 1-1
        1125 - sub Task 1-1-1
    1127 - sub Task 1-2
1126 - Main Task 2
```

Generate a flat array:

```
function listTasks($list, &$output, $level=0) {
    $output[] = array(
        'id'=>$list['task_id'],
        'name'=>$list['task_name'],
        'level'=>$level
    );
    if (array_key_exists('sub_task_id', $list)) {
        foreach ($list['sub_task_id'] as $subtasks) {
            listTasks($subtasks, $output, $level+1);
        }
    }
}
$output = array();
foreach ($a as $tasks) {
    listTasks($tasks, $output);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1123
            [name] => Main Task
            [level] => 0
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1124
            [name] => sub Task 1-1
            [level] => 1
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1125
            [name] => sub Task 1-1-1
            [level] => 2
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1127
            [name] => sub Task 1-2
            [level] => 1
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1126
            [name] => Main Task 2
            [level] => 0
        )    
)
```

Comment: Now to remove the list elements and replace it with table rows...
TYVM @Chris. Hopefully this does what I'm looking for.